# If we use "Select 8 instead of Select * " in sqlite database what will be the result?

Tags: sqlite

If we use `Select 8` instead of `Select *` in sqlite database what will be the result?

Why error not Shown?

Comment: Doesn't "select 8" (no from or where clause) just return a single column/single row result with a value of 8?  Makes sense to me.

Comment: SQL As Understood By SQLite - http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error wouldn't show because you'd not be doing anything wrong. You would simply get returned the value '8'

Answer (score 0):

If you `Select 'Something'`
from nowhere, SQL will just return 'Something'.